# How to properly unit test jQuery's .ajax() promises using Jasmine and/or Sinon?

Tags: unit-testing, jquery, jasmine, sinon

I've got a fairly straightforward function which returns a jQuery .ajax() promise as such:

```
CLAW.controls.validateLocation = function(val, $inputEl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: locationServiceUrl + 'ValidateLocation/',
        data: {
            'locationName': val
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $inputEl.addClass('busy');
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        // some success clauses
    }).fail(function(result) {
        // some failure clauses
    }).always(function() {
        // some always clauses
    });
}
```

For the most part, this new promises interface works like a dream, and eliminating callback pyramids when using jQuery's .ajax() is great. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly test these promises using Jasmine and/or Sinon:

1. All of Sinon's documentation assumes you're using old-school
   callbacks; I don't see a single example of how to use it with
   promises/deferreds
2. When attempting to use a Jasmine or Sinon spy to spy on $.ajax, the
   spy is effectively overwriting the promise, so its `done`, `fail`,
   and `always` clauses no longer exist on the ajax function, so the promise never resolves and tosses an error instead

I'd really just love an example or two of how to test these new jQuery .ajax() promises with the aforementioned testing libs. I've scoured the 'net fairly intensely and haven't really dredged up anything on doing so. The one resource I did find mentioned using Jasmine.ajax, but I'd like to avoid that if possible, seeing as Sinon provides most of the same capabilities out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

It is not that complex actually. It suffices to return a promise and resolve it according to your case.

For example:

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function (req) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.resolve(data_you_expect);
    return d.promise();
});
```

for a success, or

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function (req) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.reject(fail_result);
    return d.promise();
});
```

for a failure.

For Jasmine 2.0 the syntax has changed slightly:

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (req) {});
```

the method .andCallFake() does not exist in Jasmine 2.0

Comment: Any ideas for the Sinon way?

Comment: @ggozad what will you suggest for the code in the following question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626366/how-to-do-unit-testing-jquery-promises/25627013

Comment: @ggozad `andCallFake` has a new syntax in Jasmine 2.0. Now it's `and.callFake`. Reference: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.callFake</code>

Answer (score 17):

something along these lines / with sinon and jQuery deferreds

```
ajaxStub = sinon.stub($, "ajax");

function okResponse() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  d.resolve( { username: "testuser", userid: "userid", success: true } );
  return d.promise();
};

function errorResponse() {
 var d = $.Deferred();
 d.reject({},{},"could not complete");
 return d.promise();
};

ajaxStub.returns(okResponse());
ajaxStub.returns(errorResponse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach with just javascript.

```
quoteSnapshots: function (symbol, streamId) {
                var FakeDeferred = function () {
                    this.error = function (fn) {
                        if (symbol.toLowerCase() === 'bad-symbol') {
                            fn({Error: 'test'});
                        }
                        return this;
                    };
                    this.data = function (fn) {
                        if (symbol.toLowerCase() !== 'bad-symbol') {
                            fn({});
                        }
                        return this;
                    };
                };

                return new FakeDeferred();
            }
```

The if statements inside of each callback are what I use in my test to drive a success or error execution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @ggozad won't work if you use things like `.complete()`.

But, hooray, jasmine made a plugin to do exactly this: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.Ajax.install();
});

afterEach(function() {
  jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
});

//in your tests
expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe('/some/cool/url');
```