# How to test jQuery beforeSend method with Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

I've found out how to [test promises in jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165885/2205266), but I couldn't find a way to test the **beforeSend** method.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '...',
    beforeSend: function() {
        methodToBeTested();
    }
});
```

I do need the code to run before the request is sent so using the *always* promise is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my slightly hackie feeling solution but it worked for me.

```
it('test beforeSend', function() {

    spyOn(window, 'methodToBeTested')

    spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(options) {

        options.beforeSend();
        expect(methodToBeTested).toHaveBeenCalled();

        //this is needed if you have promise based callbacks e.g. .done(){} or .fail(){}
        return new $.Deferred();
    });

    //call our mocked AJAX
    request()
});
```

You could also try the Jasmine AJAX plugin https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if ( $.isFunction($.fn.beforeSend) ) {
//function exists
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can access the arguments passed on to the spied ajax call later:

```
$.ajax.calls.argsFor(0)[0].beforeSend();
//instead of argsFor(), you can use first(), mostRecent(), all() ...
```

This is in case you do not want to have beforeSend() called each time.