# How do you spy on a call back in an ajax call with jasmine?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine, enyo

I'm currently using enyo and I have a function on a component that takes a callback function and makes an ajax call, then calls the callback on success. I can't seem to figure out how to spy on the callback function.

```
enyo.kind({
  name: 'Login',
  isLoggedIn: function (callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/checkLogin'
      })
      .done(function (data) {
         /* Some logic here */
         return callback.apply(null, data);  //IF all goes well this should call the spy
      })
      .fail(function(){/*Fail Stuff*/});
  }
  ....
});
```

For the test I have:

```
describe('Valid User', function() {
   var ajaxSpy;
   var loginTest = new Login();
   beforeEach( function () {

      ajaxSpy = spyOn($, 'ajax').andReturn({
         done: function (fn ) {
             fn();
         },
         fail: function (){}
      });
   });

   it("should call the callback", function () {
      var spy = jasmine.createSpy("spy");
      loginTest.isLoggedIn(spy);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
 }
```

In this case when this runs the callback becomes undefined, I think it's probably because of the ajax spy intercepting it but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the ajax call is doing is returning something call a `promise`.

There are various articles you can look on this regards:

- [How to properly unit test jQuery's .ajax() promises using Jasmine and/or Sinon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13148356/1959948)
- [JavaScript with Promises and Jasmine](http://www.carlosble.com/2013/03/unit-testing-javascript-with-promises-and-jasmine/)
- [Stubbing Out $.ajax in Jasmine](https://coderwall.com/p/ogjloq)

But bottom line here are some sample code on how to achieve this:

```
spyOn( $, 'ajax' ).andCallFake( function (params) {     
  params.success({foo: 'bar'});       
});

spyOn( $, "ajax" ).andCallFake( function (params) {         
  params.error({foo: "bar"});       
});
```