# How to do unit testing jQuery Promises?

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, promise

I have the following four functions where two(), three(), and four() will be called when promise resolution happens with parameter. Let me explain, a bit further.

When I call function one(), I pass the default parameter value, but function two() will be called with the resolved value of promise in function one(). Similar logic follows for functions two(), three() and four().

```
  function one(arg) {

  var deferred = $.Deferred(); // Don't worry yet what this is until after you understand the flow

  console.log("Starting one's ajax with arg: " + arg);
  $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      success: function() {

          // Here's where you want to call the next function in the
          // list if there is one. To do it, call deferred.resolve()
          console.log('Finished with one. Ready to call next.');
          deferred.resolve("This is one's result");

      }

  });

  // The deferred object has a "promise" member, which has a "then" function
  return deferred.promise();
}

function two(arg) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  console.log("Starting two's ajax with arg: " + arg);
  $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      success: function() {

          // Again, this is where you want to call the next function
          // in the list if there is one.
          console.log('Finished with two. Ready to call next.');
          deferred.resolve("This is two's result");

      }

  });
  // The deferred object has a "promise" member, which has a "then" function
  return deferred.promise();
}

function three(arg) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  console.log("Starting three's ajax with arg: " + arg);
  $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      success: function() {

          // Again, this is where you want to call the next function
          // in the list if there is one.
          console.log('Finished with three. Ready to call next if there is one.');
          deferred.resolve("This is three's result");

      }

  });
  // The deferred object has a "promise" member, which has a "then" function
  return deferred.promise();
}

function four(arg) {
  console.log("Starting four with arg: " + arg);
  console.log("Finished synchronous four");
}

// Test it out. Call the first. Pass the functions (without calling them, so no parentheses) 
// into the "then" calls.

one("arg given to one")
  .then(two)
  .then(three)
  .then(four);
```

Comment: You have a deferred anti pattern there, $.ajax already returns a promise - use it.

Comment: Also, I can understand your code just fine but I have no idea waht you're asking here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i would like to write unit test cases of the above code so that later on i can apply similar ideas

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're testing too much. Do you really want to test that your browser is capable of doing AJAX? What for?

First step is to extract the functions so you can call/chain them in your unit tests. That way, you can create your own promises in the unit test, feed them the functions and execute them synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

After taking @Aaron's suggestions in mind, i tried the following unit testing code for a success scenario of a single function, say,function one.

```
describe('Test example-1', function () {

  it('should check promise resolved with a custom message', function () {
     spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function (req) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve("I am done");
        return d.promise();
     });

     var expectedPromise = one();
     var result = "I am done";

     expectedPromise.then(function(response) {
       expect(response).toEqual(result);
     });
 });
});
```

Both success and failure examples I have pushed in my github repo:

https://github.com/pulakb/UnitTesting-Promises/tree/master/Jasmine/jQuery