# How to test JQuery fail callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is jquery function:

```
$.get("/url", function(){

   //success
}).fail(function(){
  //fail     <---- how to make code go in there.
});
```

Problem is how to let program goes into .fail block, I use .Net MVC, However, set break point in Controller doesn't trigger a timeout exception then leads to fail callback.

Don't know how people test this.

Should I start looking at some tools ?

Comment: You're looking for what is called a "mock" library - e.g. https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax - most testing libraries will have a way to mock http requests built in( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148356/how-to-properly-unit-test-jquerys-ajax-promises-using-jasmine-and-or-sinon for an example)

Comment: Which conditions , responses should call `.fail()` ? Tried utilizing `.always()` , defining "success" , "fail" conditions for all responses within `.always()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Controller method:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Comment: In any recent version of MVC, just `return HttpNotFound();` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpnotfound%28v=vs.118%29.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Use an invalid endpoint URL. You should get 404 - not found http status code error.